Multimeter fuse
Hello guys my multimeter has no fuse or no fuse to put into it where can i put my fuse ? 

Have you checked the other side of the PCB?

you could use a fused test-lead.

I don't know how to put this nicely but it's mind boggling to me that you post a question like this without mentioning the multimeter model. It would have been so easy.

Hello the multimeter is aneng Dt-9205a its a very cheap multimeter

This meter does not appear to have fuses in either the 10A or mA circuits. The resistors (the two in  parallel, or R44, for the respective inputs will shift in value or fail if subjected to a very high current.
This kind of cheap meter is dangerously unsuitable for mains circuits- do not use it for such applications. A proper fuse for that kind of circuit is relatively large and probably more expensive than the entire meter.

I notice in the photos of that model of meter the front appears to be printed "unfused" for the 10A range (it is) and fused for the 200mA range. Unless there is a fuse hidden on the other side of the PCB, that appears to be  untrue.

I would expect the fuse to be in the line of the 10A socket, but indeed there's none. The socket is directly connected to the shunt resistors R* (bottom center of image), whose other side is connected to the COM socket. Check your manual, I am quite sure it says something along the lines of "Maximum current: 10A for 30 seconds".
It is quite normal that the high current measurement mode of a multimeter can only be used for a short period of time. But the question is what happens if you exceed that time (indicated in the manual). In this (presumably rather cheap) multimeter, I fear it would break or even start to burn. If it had a fuse, this would go, preventing further damage.
